# Falha de logon numa aplicação em IIS ao tentar conectar com SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, windows, iis

Quando rodo uma aplicação do tipo *site* no visual studio, as conexões com o banco de dados funcionam normalmente. Porém ao tentar rodar no IIS 7 para realizar alguns testes, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Não é possível abrir o banco de dados "XXX" solicitado pelo logon. Falha de logon.
>
> Falha de logon do usuário 'IIS APPPOOL\DotNet4'.

O Banco específico com o qual estou tendo dificuldades para me conectar deixei o método de autenticação configurado para ser acessado através do logon do usuário do Windows.

A `conectionString` do meu `Web.config` está parecida com isso:

```
<add name="LocalConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXX;Connect Timeout=3000; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Nota**: Me disseram que eu deveria ir no *pool de aplicativos* e configurar a opção *Identidade* com o sendo a do meu usuário, porém meu usuário tem senha e não está aceitando eu adicioná-lo nesse diálogo:

[image: Inserir usuário em "Identity" no IIS]

Comment: Já temos respostas que atendem a sua dúvida, mas só queria deixar o link do [SO-En](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0) pra reforçar as respostas!

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisto https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericparvin/2015/04/14/how-to-add-the-applicationpoolidentity-to-a-sql-server-login/ e nisto https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: extra: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities-and-sql-server-express

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso não tem a ver com configuração do IIS em si. O erro diz que o usuário **IIS APPPOOL\DotNet4** não consegue se conectar ao SQL Server.

Isso acontece com porque sua aplicação ASP.NET está usando ***Integrated Security***, isto quer dizer que a aplicação irá utilizar o usuário configurado no *pool* ao qual ela pertence para se conectar ao SQL Server.

Muito provavelmente, ao instalar o SQL Server você definiu que apenas o usuário atual teria acesso ao banco.

Por isso, é necessário adicionar o usuário **IIS APPPOOL\DotNet4** como um *login* do SQL Server.

1. Abra o SSMS e expanda o nó *security*
2. Clique com o botão direito em *logins* e depois em *new login*
3. Em *Login Name* digite o nome do usuário que aparece no erro.

   Obs.: Eu já vi muita gente falar que não se deve clicar em *search*, porque acontece algum erro. Então, por via das dúvidas, apenas cole o nome do usuário no campo de texto.

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma outra opção é alterar a forma de conexão para um usuário do próprio SQL Server. Se você configurou algum usuário na instalação, pode usá-lo apenas mudando a sua *string* de conexão para

```
<add name="LocalConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXX;
     Connect Timeout=3000; User ID=XXXX; Password=XXXX;
     MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Se não houver usuário cadastrado ou caso não lembre a senha configurada na instalação é só abrir a mesma tela dos passos acima, escolher ***SQL Server Authentication*** e entrar com as credenciais.

Comment: Creio que seja isto também!

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Eu fiz todos os passos a primeira vez e estava dando pau porque eu tinha duas instâncias do SQLServer e infelizmente configurei na errada. Agora funcionou certinho.

Comment: Olhei o event view do Windows para saber qual usuário estava tetando acessar o BD. Fiz o procedimento como descrito acima e tudo funcionou. Obrigado por compartilhar.

Answer (score 3):

O **IIS** roda um usuário próprio e o mesmo não esta autorizado a logar no seu servidor acontece isso. Provavelmente o usuário que está autorizado é o seu usuário do windows e não o do **IIS**.

Para resolver isso você pode criar um usuário do **SQL Server** para efetuar a conexão no banco e alterar sua string de conexão para se conectar com ele. Sua string de conexão ficaria assim:

```
<add name="LocalConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXX;Connect Timeout=3000; User ID=USUARIO;Password=SENHA;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Ou autorizar o usuário do **IIS** a se conectar no seu banco

Answer (score -4):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Run this in sql

SQL

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool')

BEGIN

```
CREATE LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] 
  FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], 
  DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
```

END
GO

CREATE USER [ContosoUniversityUser] 
  FOR LOGIN [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'ContosoUniversityUser'
GO

Comment: Ola Marcelo, tente escrever uma resposta mais detalhada explicando a solucao do problema, e evite utilizar links pois esses podem sair do ar um dia e fazer com que sua resposta fique incompleta =)